# Open Generics Registration

Tags: dryioc

Suppose I have the following classes:

```
public class Setup { }

public class Configuration<T> where T : class
{
    internal Configuration(Setup setup) { }
}

public class Process<T> where T : class
{
    internal Process(Configuration<T> configuration) { }
}
```

I want to register these classes in DryIoc and need each `Process<T>` to be singleton (as would be `Configuration<T>`). So, `Process<ClassA>` would resolve the same instance, and `Process<ClassB>` will do the same. But `Process<ClassA>` and `Process<ClassB>` would be 2 different instances.
The same applies to `Configuration<T>`.
How would I register these 3 classes to achieve what I need?
**Note that constructors are internal**.
This is what I've done without success:

```
var container = new Container();
container.Register<Setup>(Reuse.Singleton);
container.Register(typeof (Configuration<>), 
    made: Made.Of(typeof (Configuration<>).GetConstructorOrNull(true, typeof (Setup))));
container.Register(typeof(Process<>), Reuse.Singleton,
    Made.Of(typeof(Process<>).GetConstructorOrNull(true, typeof(Configuration<>))));
```

I get: "An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in DryIoc.dll but was not handled in user code" when, as an example I do
`var a = container.Resolve<Process<EventArgs>>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with getting constructor from generic type. For now you may use DryIoc API to get `ConstructorWithResolvableArgumentsIncludingNonPublic`:

Working sample looks [like that](https://dotnetfiddle.net/txYKco):

```
var container = new Container();

container.Register<Setup>(Reuse.Singleton);

container.Register(typeof(Configuration<>), Reuse.Singleton,
    made: FactoryMethod.ConstructorWithResolvableArgumentsIncludingNonPublic);

container.Register(typeof(Process<>), Reuse.Singleton,
    FactoryMethod.ConstructorWithResolvableArgumentsIncludingNonPublic);

var p = container.Resolve<Process<EventArgs>>();
```

In future versions it will be more simple like `FactoryMethod.Constructor(includeNonPublic: true)`.

#### Update with workaround:

This is an actual issue in DryIoc 2.9.7 with creating singletons with internal constructor. The fix is on the way. For now you can use a workaround by disabling certain singleton optimizations with rule:

```
var container = new Container(rules => rules.WithoutEagerCachingSingletonForFasterAccess());
```

Updated [live sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UFwS4d).

#### Update with fix:

The problem is fixed in [DryIoc 2.10](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DryIoc.dll)

Comment: Thanks, @dadhi.There's still one big problem: Configuration<> must resolve Singleton instances.If I change the registration to `container.Register(typeof (Configuration<>), Reuse.Singleton,                 FactoryMethod.ConstructorWithResolvableArgumentsIncludingNonPublic);`, I get the exception: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Constructor on type 'ConsoleApplication1.Program+Configuration`1[[System.EventArgs, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' not found."

Comment: What DryIoc version do you use? What is the target platform? As you see from live code at https://dotnetfiddle.net/txYKco everything is working on .NET 4.5 and DryIoc 2.9.7

Comment: OK, looking at problem

Comment: Hey, the problem is in DryIoc latest optimizations. I've updated the answer with workaround for now.

Comment: Thanks, it's working properly now. Looking forward to the next version. Keep up the good work,